# How to send msg.payload from function node to template node

Tags: node-red

How to send `msg.payload` from function node(tool) to template node(html)?

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // function test() {
    //      document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = msg.payload;
    // }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
    <h1 id="test1">{{msg.payload}}</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help if you included what you already have in the in the function node

Comment: @hardillb
sorry, I didn't get you

in the function node, I wrote like this
msg.payload = "hello"; return msg;

Comment: **Edit the question** to include all the code in the function node

Comment: in the function node, I wrote like this
msg.payload = "hello"; return msg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using `{{msg.payload}}` in the template node. The values pulled in via mustache are keyed from the `msg` object. So the correct mustache template is `{{payload}}`.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // function test() {
    //      document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = {{payload}};
    // }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
    <h1 id="test1">{{payload}}</h1>
</body>
```

The **Info** sidebar in Node-RED gives examples of what to use.